# Playing animation in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, mfc

In MFC dialog there is a control which uses for playing animation like the .avi files.
The question is I want to pause and resume the playing avi.
using play method can start from specific frame, and stop for stop it.
The question is how can I get the frame number which the .avi stop playing

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the actual frame number, but you can use the (tested but undocumented) hack of specifying -1 as the *nFrom* argument to `Play()` as a way to resume the AVI from the place where you stopped.

For example, assuming `m_avi` is an instance of a `CAnimateCtrl`:

```
// toggle pause
if (m_avi.IsPlaying())
{
    // if playing, pause
    m_avi.Stop();
}
else
{
    // not playing, resume
    m_avi.Play( -1, -1,-1 );
}
```

Testing on my system (VS2012 with a UNICODE build, running on Windows 8.1 64-bit), this works fine - the `Play` continues exactly from the point where it was last stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resume playing you can just pass nTo=-1 to play up to the end of the clip. If you want to resume playing but only until some special frame, you will need to load the video in a video editor to get the number of the frame where to stop playing.